# Remote manage a Hyper-V 2012 server that is hosting the Domain Controller, while the domain controller is down

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v, domain-controller, hyper-v-server-2012

Ok, i seem to have gotten myself into a bit of a catch 22.

I have a hyper-v 2012 server which is running the Domain Controller. 
However, the Domain Controller isn't loading due to some sort of error.

I cannot remote manage the Domain Controller or use the hyper-v manager remotely, as the hyper-v server has no DC to authenticate against.

I cannot log in to the virtual machine directly from the VM Host, as hyper-v server doesn't have the ability to use hyper-v manager.

Anyone know a possible work around? 
I know i should have installed a second DC to avoid scenarios exactly like this, however i just never got to it as was busy with other things.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Should mention, it is stuck at a screen where it says "Choose an option. Then i think the options are Continue, repair and shut down. However i can only see it in the thumbnail (using corefig utility, which unfortunately doesn't let you remote desktop into the machine)

Comment: Was the DC on a CSV?

Comment: Nope. Locally stored. This set up was just the basics I was going to work on, however i didn't have time unfortunately.

Comment: I have physical access to the hyper-v host, and can login locally to that, either through the remote desktop or physically. It is just the server manager and hyper-v manager tools which i cannot use remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so heres what i did to get around it, which i guess was the obvious answer however took quite a lot of time.

First i installed a copy of windows server 2012 standard with GUI on a different server i wasn't using.
Next i copied the VM files and VHD file to the new server, in directories with the same name.
Then i created a new VM in the new server, i chose to attach the virtual hard disk later, and named it the same name as the first VM. I then went through the files, and replaced any mention of the old GUID with the new GUID. including folder names, file names, and opening the actual .xml configuration file, and using find and replace.

So far it seems to be working well, can use server manager again and hyper-v manager, DNS is working, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully remotely manage my Hyper-V Server 2012 Core in a workgroup environment. I can also remotely manage the disks on the Hyper-V server.

I wrote a quick 12-step tutorial (article and video) showing exactly what I did to get this working.

http://pc-addicts.com/12-steps-to-remotely-manage-hyper-v-server-2012-core

Hopefully this can help others who found this to be a very frustrating task.

-Chris
http://PC-Addicts.com